# R: Problems with reshaping using dcast or pivot_wider

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape2, dcast

I am having a trouble reshaping the following data frame:

```
set.seed(45)
dat1 <- data.frame(
    name = rep(c("firstID", "secondID"), each=4),
    numbers = rep(1:4, 2),
    value = rnorm(8),
    Category = rep(c("111", "22"), each=4)
)

dat1
       ID  Timestamp      value     Category
1  firstID          1  0.3407997    111 
2  firstID          2 -0.7033403    111
3  firstID          3 -0.3795377    111
4  firstID          4 -0.7460474    111
5 secondID          1 -0.8981073    22
6 secondID          2 -0.3347941    22
7 secondID          3 -0.5013782    22
8 secondID          4 -0.1745357    22
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get the follwing result:

```
 firstID        secondID      
111          22
 0.3407997   -0.8981073
 -0.7033403  -0.3347941
 -0.3795377  -0.5013782
 -0.7460474  -0.1745357
```

Comment: But category is a character and value numeric. Do you want numeric in the final output?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the following what should be the final output in the wide format?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat1 %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = numbers,
    names_from = c(name, Category),
    values_from = value
  ) %>%
  select(-numbers)
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#  firstID_111 secondID_22
#        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1       0.341      -0.898
#2      -0.703      -0.335
#3      -0.380      -0.501
#4      -0.746      -0.175
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick aswear Rui, however I am not interested in a ID_category combination.